# How to change table header that is not static

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, r-glue

I'm trying to create a table in which the headers can change from time to time which means that the headers are not static.

Kindly see the sample below.

Create variable months with the code below

```
testing<-format(Sys.Date(),"%m")
testing<-as.integer(testing)
testing<-testing -(2)
last_2_month<-month.name[testing]

teaser<-format(Sys.Date(),"%m")
teaser<-as.integer(teaser)
teaser<-teaser-1
last.month<-month.name[teaser]
```

creating table

```
Point <- c("Average success rate", "Average processing duration", "Average daily count", "Total count processed")
ss <- c(23, 41, 32, 58)
sss <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben")
dframes <- data.frame(Point,last.month,last_2_month) #creating table the table
```

what I want is that the variable for both `last.month` and l`ast_2_month` should display the true month name/variable eg January and February in the table

| Point | January | Feburary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Average success rate | CSW | Data |
| Average processing duration | CSW | Data |
| Average daily count | CSW | Data |
| Total count processed | CSW | Data |

Glo CSW Data

Answer (score 0):

This will grab all columns containing the term `month` and create a new column for each month:

```
dframes %>% pivot_longer(matches("month")) %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name)
#># A tibble: 4 × 3
#>  Point                       February   January     
#>  <chr>                       <chr>      <chr>       
#>1 Average success rate        last.month last_2_month
#>2 Average processing duration last.month last_2_month
#>3 Average daily count         last.month last_2_month
#>4 Total count processed       last.month last_2_month
```

However, according to your example, there is no information on how to map this to cell values e.g. `CSW` or `Data`